# What is the XSS real danger on internal websites?

Tags: asp.net, security, xss

Can someone explain to me the real danger, XSS can do on internal sites using Windows Authentication. I know firewall can be break and hacker can access internal site but for now let's not focus on that. I just want to know what and internal employee(hacker) can do on a Windows Authentication environment using XSS.

Thanks,

Comment: An internal employee (hacker) can do all what any external hacker can do.... only about 10 times easier. Here is a [quick comparison](https://trinity-hackers.wikispaces.com/Internal+Hackers+vs+External+Hackers).

Comment: Windows Authentication does not prevent XSS or help detecting it, so it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Assuming you don't do anything, potentially execute script in the context of your internal users' authenticated session.

Comment: Your internal users are at least as much of a threat as external ones, if not more so, since they already have authorised network access. Even if an individual personally is not a direct threat, their IT incompetence or naivety can be a big vulnerability (think social engineering, people downloading links they shouldn't etc etc etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even for an internal website, XSS prevention is important, because of what @shawkyz1 said, but, in my opinion, more so because of what @Racil-Hilan said.

The easiest way to gain access to a company's data is to apply for a job. If you're inside, you're trusted. Imagine that an employee is pissed off with the company, for example because he's heard he'll be laid off. He can cause tremendous damage with XSS, for example by injecting a script which also pipes all input to a location from which he can steal it as his leisure.

Or perhaps he doesn't even steal the data, but cause tremendous misinformation by slightly altering messages users try to send, for example by randomly incrementing numbers, or with a small change exchanging "do" and "do not".

Answer (score 2):

Windows Authentication does not prevent XSS attacks or help detecting them, so it is irrelevant to the question.

An internal employee (hacker) can do all what any external hacker can do.... only about 10 times easier. Here is a [quick comparison](https://trinity-hackers.wikispaces.com/Internal+Hackers+vs+External+Hackers).

But practically speaking, because internal hackers can access information much easier and in more ways than external hackers, they usually use less sophisticated methods. They focus more on covering their tracks.

But then, who said that internal hackers have to do it from inside? Unlike the external hackers, they have the option to do it from both inside and outside. An employee can go to a coffee shop and perform an XSS attack (or any other attack) just like any external hacker. Their much deeper knowledge of the internal systems will make any attack much easier. Also IT employees can use the projects that are under their control to attack (XSS or otherwise) other projects that are not under their control.

The possibilities are limitless. It's nearly impossible to protect yourself from internal hackers. Your only hope is to find the tracks. The good news is that if you find the tracks, it is usually much easier to reach and punish internal hackers as long as they haven't fled the country.

That, however, doesn't mean that you don't need to bother. Your coworker can probably access your office, and even break the lock on your drawer and reach your wallet that you put there while you're having your lunch in the kitchen, but you still don't put your wallet on the desk in plain sight, do you? Well, at least you don't leave in on the table in the conference room. The better you protect your assets, the more sophisticated methods the hackers have to use, and the more likely they will leave tracks behind.

Answer (score 1):

You can't ignore the security aspects for your internal Websites just because of the fact you believe that they aren't visibile to the outside world.

There were so far many cases of different companies ignoring the security of their internal apps just because they think it's safe. But...

you said your Website is behind a firewall. Are you 100% sure of the firewall configurations and that no one would be able to access it?

Are you 100% sure that your firewall is safe and no one could break it?

Are you 100% of your server configurations and this website is only accessible from your Internal network?

Are you 100% sure that there's no possible way to access this internal Website/Database/App or whatever using the public Interface that is visible to the outside world?

Also you mentioned that it's vulnerable for **XSS**. The fact that you ignored XSS could also mean that there are more dangerous vulnerabilities that you haven't found yet or maybe didn't bother to find because you believe that it's just an **internal** website.

Also as @Racil Hilan pointed out in his answer. An insider could also exploit such a vulnerability.